# Does our local time speed up as the Universe expands?

Tags: cosmology, time

Starting from a simplified radial Freidman Walker metric we have
$$ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + a(t)^2 dr^2 $$
How does one measure one's proper time operationally?

One times a light beam along an element of proper distance $ds$. Thus an element of proper time $d\tau$ is given by
$$d\tau = \frac{ds}{c}$$ 
From the metric above we have an element of proper distance $ds$ (where $dt=0$) given by
$$ds = a(t) dr$$
Thus
$$d\tau = \frac{a(t)dr}{c}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Now light travels on a null geodesic where $ds=0$ so from the above metric we also have
$$\frac{a(t)dr}{dt} = c\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
Substituting Equation (2) into Equation (1) we find
$$d\tau = dt$$
Thus an interval of our proper time $d\tau$ is the same as an interval of cosmological time $dt$ provided we measure the time light takes to travel an **expanding** distance $ds$.
But our clocks don't expand with the Universe. They are rigid like we are. Thus if we measure our proper time interval $d\tau$ we would use
$$d\tau = \frac{dr}{c}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
where $dr$ is a distance interval that does not expand with the Universe.
If we now substitute the light-path expression (2) into Equation (3) we find
$$d\tau = \frac{dt}{a(t)}$$
This seems to imply our local proper time will speed up as the Universe expands.
Is this right?? :)

Comment: Why was this *downvoted*?. Looks like a perfectly reasonable misconception .                                                                           +1 to reverse the downvote .

Answer (score 2):

First, it is Friedmann not Freidman. And the metric is the Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric or FLRW metric.

Second, proper time $d\tau=ds/c$ is not valid for null geodesics except as formal meaningless parameter (i.e., it cannot be interpreted as time).

Third, the FLRW metric describes a homogeneous Universe, therefore time is the same everywhere and given by $t$. There is not such a thing as a cosmological time and a different local time.

Fourth, you are combining mutually incompatible equations and obtaining inconsistent results.